# Open/Load URL in Background

Tags: javascript, html, url

I need to open several URLs to trigger some actions. It is necessary to load/open the URL, to trigger the action.

As a simple ex.

Loading url: .../RedLedOn -> turns a Red LED on

Loading url: .../BlueLedOn -> turns a Blue LED on

Loading url: .../BlueLedOff -> turns a Blue LED off

Is there any way to load a URL, hidden in the background, so that the action gets triggered but the user stays at the website without opening a huge amount of new Windows/Tabs in the Background? Any other Ideas how to solve that? There is no way around calling the URLs unfortunately.

Thanks and Best Mo

Answer (score 1):

How about [window.fetch?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

`fetch('http://example.com/BlueLedOn')` would http request the URL and nothing more.

Comment: Would that call whatever scripts used to turn on/off the blue LEDs on that page though?

Comment: `fetch` itself only sends a http request in the background. Edit: it won't execute javascript on the fetched URL, sorry if that's what OP is looking for I misunderstood.

Comment: volt is right. I need to load a script, so fetch is not working unfortunately.
However your suggestion was helpful anyway in other concerns :)